# CSM setting won't stay?

Tags: bios

I am on an ASUS laptop currently and I was getting it to boot from the legacy Windows 10. I reset the BIOS and set launch csm to enabled. I saved settings and found out it was set back to disabled.

Is there anything else I need to look out for before enabling csn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to disable secure boot because CSM doesn't support it.

If that doesn't work, reset BIOS to defaults, reboot and try again.

If that still doesn't resolve the problem, make sure you have latest BIOS version.

Answer (score -1):

### CSM resets to "Disabled" every time?

Here are some tricks I did (Gigabyte z690 UD):

1. Set "Windows 10 Features" to "Other OS"
2. Set "Secure Boot" to "Disabled"
3. Disable the iGPU (cpu internal graphics)

If "Secure-Boot" is not configurable (disabled and grayed-out), there are some features that force "Secure-Boot" to stay active. To disable those features forcing Secure-Boot you need to configure:

1. Settings -> Miscellaneous -> Trusted Computing -> Secure Device Support: Disable
2. Settings -> Miscellaneous -> Intel Platform Trust Technology (PTT): Disable (**Warning: Sometimes the Intel PTT is reactivated**)
3. Set "Re-Size BAR Support" to "Disabled"
4. Set "Settings" -> "IO Ports" -> "APP Center Download & Install" to "Disabled"

Warning: After you changed "Secure Boot" from On to Off, you need to restart your computer in order to enable CSM.